# .NET 4 ClickOnce expired certificate

Tags: .net, .net-4.0, clickonce

I just tried to publish an update to my .NET 4 [WPF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Presentation_Foundation) application and received the following error:

> Error 2   An error occurred while signing: Failed to sign
>   bin\Debug\app.publish\setup.exe. SignTool Error: The signer's
>   certificate is not valid for signing. SignTool Error: An error
>   occurred while attempting to sign: bin\Debug\app.publish\setup.exe

I checked the certificate, and it did expire last month so that is the reason why I'm getting this error message...

Now, according to the MSDN article *[Certificate Expiration in ClickOnce Deployment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff369721.aspx)*, I can just create a new certificate, publish and everything should be fine, but since I don't want to deal with this expiring certificate issue any more and that same article states the following:

> You can use MakeCert to create your own certificate and specify the
>   end date so you don’t have to deal with the expired certificate issue
>   **until you upgrade to .NET 4.0 and no longer have to deal with it**.

How do I get to the point where I "no longer have to deal with it"?

Can I just uncheck "Sign the ClickOnce manifest" checkbox in the Signing section of my application properties and not have to deal with this any more considering this is a .NET 4 application or not?

If not, can I use the `makecert.exe` tool to generate a certificate that expires in 2099 and use that to sign my application?

If not, how exactly can I avoid dealing with certificates using .NET 4 going forward?

Comment: In case there are no answers and someone else has the same problem I created a new certificate using makecert with expiration date in 2099 and used that to sign the ClickOnce manifest... the installed app updated fine, did not have to uninstall/reinstall...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a new certificate using `makecert` with an expiration date of 2099 and used that to sign the ClickOnce manifest.

The installed application updated fine, and I did not have to uninstall/reinstall...